# Youtube video on Ipad - How to disable related videos (rel=0 ignored)

Tags: ipad, safari, youtube

Is there anyway to disable related videos showing at the end of an embedded youtube video for iPad?

When testing the following link, I still see related videos on iPad even though rel=0 is set:

http://music.ece.drexel.edu/~mzimmerman/OCPCarmen/iFrameEmbed.htm

Am using iOS5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found link on Youtube API forum stating that fix was added in last couple of days and should be live by 2/11 at latest

http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/c824a831f78f4923/b2628eb2bf32ced6?show_docid=b2628eb2bf32ced6&pli=1